# System.IO.Directory.Exists fails inside LINQ statement, but not in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net

.Net Framework 4.7.2

That was a very surprisingly issue...

I have this routine to get all available Inventor templates from local disk, no matter which version it is:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetInventorTemplates_FAILS()
{
    var publicPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBLIC");
    var autodeskPath = Path.Combine(publicPath, "Documents", "Autodesk");
    var inventorPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(autodeskPath, "*Inventor*");
    var templatePaths = inventorPaths.Select(path => Path.Combine(path, "Templates"));
    var templates = templatePaths.Where(Directory.Exists).SelectMany(path => Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    //                     throws error ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return templates;
}
```

If I run this code, I got this error:

```
System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[System.String].get_Items() calls into native method Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetFullPathName(char*, int, char*, System.IntPtr). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.
```

What makes it more crazy is if I rewrite the code, to manually call `Directory.Exists` and it works!!!

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetInventorTemplates_WORKS()
{
    var publicPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBLIC");
    var autodeskPath = Path.Combine(publicPath, "Documents", "Autodesk");
    var inventorPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(autodeskPath, "*Inventor*");
    var templatePaths = inventorPaths.Select(path => Path.Combine(path, "Templates"));

    foreach (var path in templatePaths)
        if (Directory.Exists(path)) // <- no exception!!!
            foreach (var template in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                yield return template;
}
```

You'll get the same result if you just check via *QuickWatch*:

[image: templatePaths.Where(Directory.Exists) via QuickWatch dialog]

[image: Directory.Exists(templatePaths.First()) via QuickWatch dialog]

For now I can use the rewrited version, but I was a lot curious if I'm the lucky one... :-)

Comment: Do you have an *actual* problem? The error complains that the *debugger view* can't evaluate the query. At this point you only have a query, not a list of paths. The debugger would have to execute that query to retrieve the results. When your method returns the IQueryable query as an IEnumerable it forces the execution of the query and actually returns the results as an IEnumerable

Comment: This isn't a problem anyway, and not uncommon either. If you create a watch on an IQueryable there are a *lot* of cases where the watch can't be evaluated. That doesn't mean the code itself has a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a .NET problem. The code will run fine, you don't have to change anything. The *debugger* says it can't safely execute the query in the watch window so it can't display any results. The error explains that

> Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

`template` isn't a list of documents, it's a query that hasn't been executed yet. The debugger would have to execute that query to retrieve and the results.

This is neither a problem nor uncommon. There are several cases where the debugger can't execute a LINQ query or enumerate an IEnumerable safely and display the results. If you want to inspect the results, execute the query explicitly eg with `ToList`.

**PS**

It's probably a good idea to use a globbing library like [Glob](https://github.com/kthompson/glob) (3M NuGet downloads) to replace all this code with :

```
var root = new DirectoryInfo(autodeskPath);
var templates = root.GlobFileSystemInfos("*Inventor*/Templates/**/*.*");
```

.NET Core itself uses [file globbing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing) through the [Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing) package.

```
Matcher matcher = new();
matcher.AddIncludePatterns(new[] { "*Inventor*/Templates/**/*.*" });

foreach (string file in matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(autodeskPath))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @panagiotis-kanavos your explanation was clear enough to lead me to revisit the code and get the original exception message but guess what!
The original code is not throwing error anymore!
Should I just delete this question or leave it for my eternal shame? :-D

Comment: No - it's an unexpected situation even when you know about this. You may want to look at globbing libraries though, which would allow you to replace the entire method with `root.GlobFileSystemInfos("*Inventor*/Templates/**/*.*");

Comment: @Caverna I added two examples of globbing libraries